# How to install a specific version of libpython on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Prefix:** I am currently working with some legacy machines in the field and need to install specific versions of libpython. These machines do not have access to the internet so apt-get or pip is not an option. These machines are currently running Ubuntu 16.

I am not entirely sure what libpython even is BUT I was able to install it with `sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev` on my personal machine. However, there is a very high probability that I will need a specific version.

**Question:** How do I install a specific version of libpython so that the Shared Objects (.so) and head (.a) files are created properly?

Here are the files that were created via my 3.6 install:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-i386-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-i386-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-i386-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-i386-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m-pic.a
```

**More Info:**
There is a proprietary install .deb that is firing off these errors saying the following:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of [Program Name]:
 [Program Name] depends on libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.5); however:
  Package libpython3.6 is not installed.
```

Comment: you installed `libpython3.6-dev` on your local machine, which are the *development headers* to the libpython3.6 package. Probably, they depend on the actual `libpython3.6` package.

Comment: "I don't know what..." and "very high probability that…": Nope, let's not spend your (and our!) time helping you do something that might or might not help you. Explain, in detail, why you think you need what you think you need, which problem you're solving this way, and how the problem arises.

Comment: Okay, I added some more info, hopefully, that is enough. I will keep as much as I can think of.

Comment: well, the error message tells you exactly that you need to install libpython3.6 :) That takes out the guesswork completely :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694346/transfering-and-offline-installing-net-tools-in-an-ubuntu-server-with-no-interne/694351#694351 The 2. point, "Use `apt-offline`".

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to install libpython on machines without internet access. I can do the whole `apt-get install libpython3.6-dev` in development but when it needs to be deployed to the field that is not an option for these machines. Not to mental on this one machine here at the office it installed 3.6.2 which it needs 3.6.5 or greater...

Comment: .... I literally just linked to you to instructions on how to do exactly that. And you don't need `libpython-3.6-dev`, but `libpython3.6`, which I also already said.

Comment: Yeah sorry we commented at the same time so I didn't see that until after I posted. Looks promising thus far. If it does work I'll have you post it as an answer so you can get your points lols.

Comment: thanks, but you don't have to reward me – just happy if it works for you!